# Cadenas de caracteres como punteros en c

Tags: c, array, manejo-de-memoria, punteros

estoy aprendiendo C y entiendo perfectamente los punteros y su relación con los arrays, pero mi problema viene con las cadenas de caracteres. Se que declarar una cadena de caracteres de este modo:

```
char cadena[] = "Hola";
```

es equivalente a:

```
char cadena[] = {'H','o','l','a','\0'}
```

y que por lo tanto si quieres que una función devuelva una cadena de caracteres tienes que hacer que sea static para que la dirección de memoria sea válida fuera del ámbito de la función:

```
char *getCadena (){
    static char cadena[] = "Hola"; //static para que su dirección en la memoria sea global
    return cadena;
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que hace el compilador cuando declaras la cadena de caracteres así:

```
char *cadena = "Hola";
```

¿declara el array como static? lo pregunto porque al probarlo he visto que aun declarando una cadena de caracteres de ese modo modo dentro de una función puede ser retornada sin problemas, por lo que la dirección tiene que ser global de aun modo:

```
char *getCadena (){
char *cadena= "Hola";
return cadena;
}
```

Gracias por adelantado y un saludo

Answer (score 7):

## Allocaminento estatico

> Lo que no entiendo es que hace el compilador cuando declaras la cadena de caracteres así:
>
> `char *cadena = "Hola";`

El compilador crea el literal "Hola" en una zona solo-lectura de la memoria y `cadena` apunta a esa dirección, es decir: es el puntero `cadena` lo que esta en el Stack, no el literal "Hola". Cuando retornas, retornas la dirección del literal (donde apuntaba `cadena`) y por lo tanto es seguro de retornar.

El uso de `static` crea una diferencia, pues la variable que normalmente quedaría en el stack, queda en realidad en la memoria estática. Esto tiene otro caso de uso, es para cuando una función necesita almacenar un estado entre diferentes llamadas.

## Allocaminento automatico

ahora cuando haces...

`char cadena[] = "Hola";`

crea el literal "Hola" en una zona solo-lectura de la memoria, pero cuando se invoca la función copia el literal al arreglo cadena que esta allocada en el stack.

Aquí hay otra diferencia, este ultimo puede modificarse mientras no se cambie su largo máximo. Pues se trata de una copia.

No es seguro retronar la dirección de este arreglo pues todo la cadena se encuentra en el Stack.

## Allocaminento dinamico

Hay otro modo de allocar memoria en c, es usando `malloc` y `free` que se usan respectivamente para reservar memoria y liberar una reserva previa.

Este tipo de allocamiento se hace en el Heap, osea memoria dinámica.

Este tipo de allocamientos son seguros para retornar de una funcion, pero no debes olvidarte de liberarla (con `free`) pues sino el programa acabara usando toda la memoria y se detendra por OUT_OF_MEMORY

Comment: A que te refieres con que no es seguro retornar? @Emanuel Ve

Comment: @eduu15 se refiere a que dentro de una subrutina o función esa cadena "Hola" se copia a la pila, si al retornar de la función devuelves el puntero a esa dirección de memoria los valores que haya se pisarán en cualquier momento, y por lo tanto generando resultados inesperados.

Answer (score 0):

Es equivalente a esto,
el compilador hace esto:

```
char cadena_aux[] = {'H','o','l','a','\0'}
char* cadena = &(cadena_aux[0]);
```

Es decir, hace varias cosas:

- reservar un determinado espacio en memoria GLOBAL (no STACK, no HEAP)
- rellenar/inicializar esa memoria con los chars adecuados.
- poner la direccion de memoria (osease, un puntero) del primer char del array en la variable cadena. Coloquialmente, en este ejemplo, el puntero cadena apunta a la 'H'.