# error: ‘...’ was not declared in this scope y error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

soy nueva en programación y estoy haciendo un código para clasificar a partir de condicionales, los diferentes tipos de instrumentos musicales. Y al momento de ingresar un
instrumento debe mostrar a qué tipo de instrumento musical pertenece, este es el código que realicé:

```
int main()
{
    char instrumento;
    std::cout << "********Tipos de instrumentos musicales********" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Escriba alguno de los siguientes instrumentos para saber a que tipo pertenece (no incluir tildes):" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Saxofón" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Flauta" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Clarinete" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Trompeta" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Guitarra" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Arpa" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Violín" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Piano" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Timbal" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tambor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Platillos" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bombo" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bajo eléctrico" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Guitarra eléctrica" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Theremín" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sintetizador" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> instrumento;
    
    if(instrumento == Saxofon || instrumento == Flauta|| instrumento == Clarinete || instrumento == Trompeta)
    {
        std::cout << "El"<< instrumento << "pertenece al tipo de instrumento de viento"<< std::endl;
    }
    
    else if (instrumento == Guitarra || instrumento == Arpa|| instrumento == Violin || instrumento == Piano)
    {
        std::cout << "El"<< instrumento << "pertenece al tipo de instrumento de cuerda" << std::endl;
    }
    
    else if (instrumento == Timbal || instrumento == Tambor|| instrumento == Platillos || instrumento == Bombo )
    {
       std::cout << "El"<< instrumento << "pertenece al tipo de instrumento de percusión" << std::endl; 
    }
    
    else if (instrumento == Bajo electrico || instrumento == Guitarra electrica|| instrumento == Theremin || instrumento == Sintetizador)
    {
        std::cout << "El"<< instrumento << "pertenece al tipo de instrumento eléctrico" << std::endl;
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Ha ingresado un instrumento no valido, vuelva a intentar" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me dice lo siguiente:

```
main.cpp:82:54: error: ‘Tambor’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (instrumento == Timbal || instrumento == Tambor|| instrumento == Platillos || instrumento == Bombo )
                                                      ^~~~~~
main.cpp:82:78: error: ‘Platillos’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (instrumento == Timbal || instrumento == Tambor|| instrumento == Platillos || instrumento == Bombo )
                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:82:106: error: ‘Bombo’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (instrumento == Timbal || instrumento == Tambor|| instrumento == Platillos || instrumento == Bombo )
                                                                                                          ^~~~~
main.cpp:87:29: error: ‘Bajo’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (instrumento == Bajo electrico || instrumento == Guitarra electrica|| instrumento == Theremin || instrumento == Sintetizador)
                             ^~~~
main.cpp:87:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘electrico’
     else if (instrumento == Bajo electrico || instrumento == Guitarra electrica|| instrumento == Theremin || instrumento == Sintetizador)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

Alguien me podría ayudar a saber bien por qué me sale ese error y cómo podría solucionarlo? Muchas gracias de antemano

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

He agregado las comillas como me lo indicó un comentario, pero ahora se presenta el siguiente error:

```
main.cpp:35:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(instrumento == "Saxofon" || instrumento == "Flauta"|| instrumento == "Clarinete" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
                       ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:51: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(instrumento == "Saxofon" || instrumento == "Flauta"|| instrumento == "Clarinete" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
                                                   ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:77: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(instrumento == "Saxofon" || instrumento == "Flauta"|| instrumento == "Clarinete" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:107: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(instrumento == "Saxofon" || instrumento == "Flauta"|| instrumento == "Clarinete" || instrumento == "Trompeta")
                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:40:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"|| instrumento == "Violin" || instrumento == "Piano")
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:40:58: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"|| instrumento == "Violin" || instrumento == "Piano")
                                                          ^~~~~~
main.cpp:40:82: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"|| instrumento == "Violin" || instrumento == "Piano")
                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:40:109: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"|| instrumento == "Violin" || instrumento == "Piano")
                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Timbal" || instrumento == "Tambor"|| instrumento == "Platillos" || instrumento == "Bombo" )
                             ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:56: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Timbal" || instrumento == "Tambor"|| instrumento == "Platillos" || instrumento == "Bombo" )
                                                        ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:82: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Timbal" || instrumento == "Tambor"|| instrumento == "Platillos" || instrumento == "Bombo" )
                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:112: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Timbal" || instrumento == "Tambor"|| instrumento == "Platillos" || instrumento == "Bombo" )
                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:50:29: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Bajo electrico" || instrumento == "Guitarra electrica"|| instrumento == "Theremin" || instrumento == "Sintetizador")
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:50:64: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Bajo electrico" || instrumento == "Guitarra electrica"|| instrumento == "Theremin" || instrumento == "Sintetizador")
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:50:102: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Bajo electrico" || instrumento == "Guitarra electrica"|| instrumento == "Theremin" || instrumento == "Sintetizador")
                                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:50:131: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     else if (instrumento == "Bajo electrico" || instrumento == "Guitarra electrica"|| instrumento == "Theremin" || instrumento == "Sintetizador")
                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: El problema que tienes es que en tus condiciones se deben de comparar cadenas, y las cadenas deben de ir entre comillas, por ejemplo: `instrumento == "Guitarra" || instrumento == "Arpa"`, etc., Al no tener comillas, el compilador piensa que son variables, y que esas variables no están declaradas.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: pero ahora que las agregue me dice este error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive], sabes a qué se debe?

Comment: Oooh si, no me había dado cuenta que habías declarado instrumento con char, pero lo importante es que ya lo solucionaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi solución del problema es un poco incorrecta por que repites muchas veces varios bucles y eso esta mal por que creo que se puede hacer con un solo bucle como no se mucho de programación c++ solo lo básico, pero igual espero que te sirva:

Nota: Esto sirve si solo quieres clasificar instrumento por instrumento.

CODIGO:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
const char *instrumentos[16] = {"Saxofón","Flauta","Guitarra","Arpa","Violín",
                                "Piano","Timbal","Theremín","Sintetizador","Bombo", 
                                "Bajo electrico","Guitarra eléctrica", "Clarinete", 
                                "Tambor","Platillos","Trompeta"};

const char *instrumento_viento[4] = {"Saxofón","Flauta","Clarinete","Trompeta"};
const char *instrumento_cuerda[4] = {"Guitarra","Arpa","Violin","Piano"};
const char *instrumento_percusion[4] ={"Timbal","Tambor","Platillos","Bombo"};
const char *instrumento_electrico[4] = {"Bajo electrico","Guitarra eléctrica","Theremín","Sintetizador"};

int cont_viento=0, cont_cuerda=0, cont_percusion=0, cont_electrico=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<4;j++){
        if(instrumentos[i] == instrumento_viento[j]){
            cout<<instrumento_viento[j]<<", ";
            cont_viento++;
            cout<<"=> viento"<<endl;

        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<4;j++){
        if(instrumentos[i] == instrumento_cuerda[j]){
            cout<<instrumento_cuerda[j]<<", ";
            cont_cuerda++;
            cout<<"=> cuerda"<<endl;

        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<4;j++){
        if(instrumentos[i] == instrumento_percusion[j]){
            cout<<instrumento_percusion[j]<<", ";
            cont_percusion++;
            cout<<"=> percusion"<<endl;

        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<4;j++){
        if(instrumentos[i] == instrumento_electrico[j]){
            cout<<instrumento_electrico[j]<<", ";
            cont_electrico++;
            cout<<"=> electrico"<<endl;

        }
    }
}
return 0;}
```

[image: Resulado de lo compilado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema

> error: ‘...’ was not declared in this scope

lo resolví agregando las comillas "" después de los operadores en el if, no me funcionaba porque si no pongo las "" lo lee como una variable no declarada.

Luego de eso se me presentó el error:

> error: ISO C ++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
> [-fpermissive]

Lo solucioné reemplazando char por string y agregando `std::` antes de `string`, hice esto porque como utilicé std:: en el resto del código en la declaración también debía incluirlo, esto no sería necesario si antes del int main se colocara `#include namespace std;`

Notas: Esta es mi explicación después de preguntar aquí donde Oscar G me ayudó con el primer problema, igualmente en [este](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/) foro de reddit en inglés realicé la misma pregunta y me dieron la misma respuesta. Por otro lado, en mi segunda pregunta me compartieron [este](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdstring/) enlace explicativo sobre el segundo problema, [aquí](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/mdzhqg/error_was_not_declared_in_this_scope/) les dejo mi post del foro de reddit por si quieren leer los comentarios. Cabe recalcar que soy principiante, mi solución es claramente acorde a mi nivel.

Comment: Quita ese `#include` y reemplazalo por: `using`: `using namespace std;` #include es solo una instruccion para el compilador de incluir un archivo en ese mismo archivo. Como quien dice copia y pega el código en ese mimo archivo antes de compilarse.

Comment: Y si estas aprendiendo te recomiendo que comienzes con puntero a `char` o arrays de char: [`char* o char []`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21698/cadenas-de-caracteres-como-punteros-en-c) y ya cuando sepas como usarlos puedes ir a usar la clase `string` . Dejame ver si te consigo un buen tutorial.

Comment: Para ver como realmente C y C++ ven las cadenas: https://es.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Cadenas_de_caracteres      y       http://platea.pntic.mec.es/vgonzale/cyr_0204/cyr_01/control/lengua_C/cadenas.htm

Comment: Y no conseguí un buen tutorial sobre el puntero a char o `char*` . Bueno aquí está: Cada vez que haces esto: `char* a="Hola mundo";`//El compilador guarda esa cadena en una direccion de memoria estática y el puntero a apunta a esa direccion de memoria. Por lo que puedes hacer esto: `char* a="hola";a="mundo";std::cout<<a; /* y no esto:*/char* a="hola mundo"; a[0]='a'; `//Te deberia dar un error porque está intentando modificar una ubicación de memoria estática o constante.